# Android AChartEngine : SalesComparisonChart lines do not reach the exact value

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

i am using AChartEngine library for android and i am drawing a chart using SalesComparisonChart class. but i noticed that the lines drawn does not reach the same value in number, it is drawn below the exact value like below in the photo . in category Oriental the value is 3608 and 4358 but the lines are below those values. Can someone help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create an issue in the AChartEngine issue tracker.

Until this will be fixed you can use LineChart instead of the cubic line chart or you can add custom annotations.

```
series.addAnnotation("text", x, y);
```

Comment: i found that line chart uses double values as X-Axis labels, and i need strings to be set as x-Axis labels, 
the problem is in the functions that draw the line chart, it accepts array of double as x-axis labels and i can't modify in the library. can u help me with this ?

Comment: renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "text") will let you add custom labels.

Comment: What is the status of this issue? I have the exact same problem!